# python - Eclipse doesn't extend PYTHONPATH

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, python-venv

At first I have to say that iam new with python. I installed pywin32 for python 3.6 x64 and was wondering why I still get an import error:

[image]

EDIT: error: `import win32api` => `No module named win32api`

Thats the config of my current interpreter.
[image]

I thought eclipse will extend the sys.path, when I add folders, isn't so? but as you can see there are some folders missing when I print sys.path although I added them to the PYTHONPATH.

Can someone figure out what I did wrong?

Btw: Does python look recursively in a given folder?

Comment: you didn't show us the import error you're getting.

Comment: sorry, i write `import win32api` and the error is No module named win32api

Comment: can you type `print(sys.executable)` when the import doesn't work ?

Comment: yes it prints me the path of the python.exe: `'C:\\dev\\Projects\\WebWim\\myenv\\Scripts\\python.exe'`